# Distribution of.NET form application with service based database

Tags: c#, .net, database, visual-studio-2019

I've developed a .NET (windows forms application) that i want to distribute to a friend which is not a developer. When my friend opens the generated .exe file as administrator on her computer, this error comes up.

> "Error: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server id configured to allow remote connections. (Provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database
>   Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Express is properly installed
>   and that the local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)"

From the error it seems like the application crashed because the database is not installed on my friends computer. This leaves me behind with the following questions.

1) How would someone distribute a .NET application using a service-based database?

2) Should I make an installation file (visual studio 2019) that also installs the database and eventually the .NET framework. If yes, how should I do that in visual studio 2019?

3) From the word service-based database it seems like this database is running on some server somewhere? Is this server my own computer? Or can I access this server from another computer?

Comment: SQL Server database is an MDF file.  You can de-attached the file from the database and make a copy.  Then attach on another server. The MDF file must be on the same disk drive as the SQL Server Software (could be drives c: and d: provided they are different partitions on the same physical disk).  You can also connect to a SQL Server on a remote Machine provided the credentials are set up properly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do you know if there is a way to install a server on my friends computer, when opening the .exe file? Some sort of installation file.

Comment: Just download the SQL Server Express for free from MSDN.  I would make sure you install SSMS also.  Attaching a database (MDF) file is very one instruction command from SSMS.

Comment: Allright. Thank you.